# Difference between DTO and Response Object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, architecture, request-response

What is the difference between a Response Object and DTO in software architecture? Say I want to get a list of Products in a catalog.

If ProductDTO is this,  how is a Product Response class different? Is a Product Response typically just a wrapper with a datetime, error log, or guid, or what is the prime difference? If there is not an exact or multiple answers, would like to hear top reasons in industry.

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set;},
    public string ProductName { get; set;},
    public string ProductDescription { get; set;},
    public float SalesAmount { get; set;}
}
```

I tried googling these answers, they did not have specific answer for this question,

[Reusing DTO for various request/response types vs explicitness of what is required / what should be returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349199/reusing-dto-for-various-request-response-types-vs-explicitness-of-what-is-requir)

[Data Objects for each layer(DTO vs Entity vs Response objects)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368878/data-objects-for-each-layerdto-vs-entity-vs-response-objects)

**Update:**

Trying to validate answer. Seems Rahul answer is answering difference between Domain object and DTO . Thought Response is a wrapper around DTO, not sure if true-

http://themoderndeveloper.com/the-modern-developer/requesting-a-response/

Posted here now:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398783/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-response-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen, a Response object can contain a Status Field on top of the DTO which indicates if the request has succeeded; or if not, why it has failed.

But I am not quite sure this is a documented norm.

Comment: thanks, seems to fall in line with this answer, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398783/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-response-object

Comment: Agreed Reponse object contains Dtos and also some properties to indicate the status (like error or success message)

Answer (score 11):

A `DTO (Data Transfer Object)` is an object that defines how the data will be sent over the network or application. On the other hand `Response Object` which usually holds response data from DTO's or `WebApi's or Data Access` or any other responses to client.

The `Response Object` which usually includes all/few properties of a particular `model or entity or DTO` which is usually a subset of `DTO` object. Please see below example.

**Employee Response Object:**

```
public class EmployeeResponseObject
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Designation { get; set; }    
}
```

**Employee DTO:**

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can see here. `EmployeeResponseObject` is a subset of `EmployeeDTO` which mean's `EmployeeResponseObject` has fewer properties from `EmployeeDTO`. In few scenario's we don't have to pass all information to end Client. So we will use `EmployeeResponseObject` to get required properties from `EmployeeDTO`.
You can use `LINQ` to project data to `Response Object` from `DTO`.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(EmployeeResponseObject))]
public EmployeeResponseObject GetEmployee()
{
    var employee = from e in dbContext.EmployeeDTO
                select new EmployeeResponseObject()
                {
                    Id = e.Id,
                    Name = e.Name,
                    Designation = e.Designation
                };    
    return employee;
}
```

If you use only `EmployeeDTO` to pass information to `presentation layer/View, Webforms or ConsoleApp` then your `presentation layer/View` will tightly coupled to your `domain layer`. Any changes done to `DTO Objects` requires you to change `presentation layer or controllers` which is not a good way to do it.

Sometimes `DTO` and `Response Objects` will be exactly same then why to use separate objects.
This might look unnecessary duplication of code but think when your project grows bigger specially in a big teams where many people work together on different layers of application. Here using `DTO` and `separate Response object` makes much more sense with a good programming practice. `Presentation layer/View` and the `domain layer` will become tightly coupled when you skip using `ResponseObject/ViewModelObject`.